# How to get array response in horizontal way of 3 array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sails.js

I have 3 different arrays in JavaScript, they have always the same length or may be not and I need to change response of this array in JSON format

I am getting this below response right now.:-

```
"status": "ok",
"massage": "success"
"data":{
     "Investment":[
        "file":[
            "654g6-8557-6545.xls",
            "45yj-5667-5567.docx",
            "305fh5-5547-5566.png"
           ],
          "nameOfFile":[
            "Aml_MasterFile.xsx",                      
            "Value_policy.docx",
            "Image1.png"
          ],
          "file type":[
             "Purchase agreement",
             "option agreement",
             "Profile"
          ]

      ]
}

**Expected Response** is:

"status": "ok",
"massage": "success"
"data":[
    {
    "file":"654g6-8557-6545.xls", 
    "nameOfFile": "Aml_MasterFile.xsx", 
    "file_type":"purchase agreement"
    },
    {
    "file":"45yj-5667-5567.docx", 
    "nameOfFile":"Value_policy.docx", 
    "file_type":"option agreement"
    },
    {
    "file":"305fh5-5547-5566.png", 
    "nameOfFile":"Image1.png",
    "file_type":"profile"
    }
]


**My Code:** can achieve this with just 1 map??????

Var investor_id = req param("investor_id")
Var condition = {"is_deleted":{"$ne":"1"}}

var result = await db. collection("dysinvestor").aggregate([
        {"$match" : condition},
    
        {"$project": {
            "_id":0,
            "filename":"$formData.file1",
            "original name":"$formData.origin_file1",
            "filetype":"$formData.file1_filetype",
        }},
    ]).toArray()


**My Databases Records for example**-
```

{
"_id" : "154646116164654",
"formData" : {
"file1" : [
"dsd-3ccc-47da-ds-18659sdssd98d612c.pdf",
"31610233-a813-4b06-8d34-4277f055d4d2.pdf"
],
"origin_file1" : [
"Sample_00.pdf",
"Sample_00.pdf"
],
"file1_filetype" : [
"006",
"002"
],

```
I would appreciate any help... Thanks in advance ☺️
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if I got your problem... I've used your input as sample data, the convert function transfers the input data to your desired structure...

```
let input = {
  "status": "ok",
  "massage": "success",
  "data":{
     "Investment":{
        "file":[
            "654g6-8557-6545.xls",
            "45yj-5667-5567.docx",
            "305fh5-5547-5566.png"
           ],
          "nameOfFile":[
            "Aml_MasterFile.xsx",                      
            "Value_policy.docx",
            "Image1.png"
          ],
          "file type":[
             "Purchase agreement",
             "option agreement",
             "Profile"
          ]
      }
   }
}


function convert(arg) {
    let result = {
    "status": arg.status,
    "message": arg.massage,
    "data": []
  }
  // TODO: instead of hardcoded array length, determine the largest array and use that as loop condition
  for (let i = 0; i < arg.data.Investment.file.length; i++) {
    // TODO: implement check to see if the array index exists
    let obj = {
        "file": arg.data.Investment.file[i],
      "nameOfFile": arg.data.Investment.nameOfFile[i],
      "file_type": arg.data.Investment["file type"][i]
    }
    result.data.push(obj);
  }
  return result;
}

let tmp = convert(input);
console.log(tmp);
```